# Does electric guitar's body shape really effect its sound?

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups

As I know electric guitar's sound is transferred to electric signal by Faraday's law, that a changing magnetic field produces electricity. So this is independent by shape of guitar then why so many people keep saying electric guitar's body shape is important for sound of guitar?

**Edit1:** Here it is shown :

[image]

**Edit2:** And [here it is explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-colsdWF4-s)

Comment: This question is quite similar and already has many answers: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14019/how-much-does-an-electric-guitars-body-physics-affect-the-tone-playability-et

Comment: Oh Thank you a lot I did not see it. Then this question can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the body shape won't have any effect on the way microphones are picking the sound.

However, the strings (which are vibrating) are attached to the body. Part of the string vibration will be transferred to the body and, obviously part of the vibration of the body will be transferred to the strings.

This way, the shape of the body can actually have an influence on the sound produced by the strings: if some frequencies are favored or not, depending, for instance, if the body will "resonate" well at these frequencies. The exact way it will influence the strings or vibrates is, I think, a very difficult question though. But it is clear that the strings are not attached to an "unmovable" frame like we like them to be attached in Physics…

Obviously, this is a secondary effect, but as the system body+strings is quite coupled, you can imagine the former has an effect on the behavior of the later.